# How can I use a Radio Button as a Toggle Button (Android)?

Tags: android, radio-button, toggle, togglebutton

For the purpose of looks and spacing, I need to use a Radio Button as a Toggle button, but for the life of me, can't get the dumb thing to change its state. Does anyone now how I can make a single Radio Button toggle between its checked state? I don't know if there is perhaps a way to trick it by using a Radio Group, or some if/else statement combination (although when I tried this, it seemed to think it was checked, even though it wasn't). Or perhaps make a toggle button look like a radio button?

Comment: For a simple way, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023965/3758439
It's also possible to change the checkbox square button to a round one using xml, there are solutions like that on SO.

Answer (score 2):

[RadioButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) has several methods that will let you change its state.

[toggle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#toggle%28%29)

[setChecked(boolean b)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)

The name of the widget you refer to as "Toggle Button" is called [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html) by the system. RadioButton actually extends CompoundButton. So it has access to all of the same methods.

Comment: According to the developer's page, however, the use of toggle() with a radio button will only check it, not uncheck it if it is already checked. I have yet to try it and was hoping for another idea or so before I did.

Comment: Ok, but it provides both getChecked() and setChecked(boolean b) you could use a combination of those to toggle no matter what the state is... in terms of Android RadioButton IS A Toggle Button. it will do anything that a toggle button can.

Comment: I've tried every possible combination I can think of and I can't get it to switch states. It will either stay checked or let me uncheck it, but not recheck it.

Comment: I just want to take a moment to bump this very old thread here just to ask if you figured this out? Your last comment @rphello101 is exactly what I'm dealing with now; toggles off, but can't toggle it back on. Logic doesn't seem incorrect, but it has to be if it won't turn itself back on.

Comment: @mbob98 - Sorry, I don't even remember what this project was for haha I'd go with George's alternate solution of changing a checkbox to round and simply now worry about the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton` class and override the method called `toggle()`

This does the trick:

```
@Override
public void toggle(){
  setChecked(!isChecked());
}
```